# Can't go to another picture in Modal Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, carousel

As I said .. Mostly **I can't see first image in my modal photo gallery**.
 And sometimes **I can't even go to another picture.**
I've got this problem on Google Chrome.
Maybe I have any scripts bad. Sorry but I'm not very good at JavaScript at all.
 I'll be really glad if you help me with this.
 Thanks.

**Libraries:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script async src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script async src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Script:**

```
<script>
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
                        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          images[i].onclick = function () {
              modal.style.display = "block";
              modalImg.src = this.src;
              modalImg.alt = this.alt;
              captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
          };
      }
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      span.onclick = function () {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      };
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";};
            $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', centerModal);$(window).on("resize", function () {$('.modal:visible').each(centerModal);});
```

---

**Modal Carousel:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="gallery text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-responsive item"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="256" height="171" alt="" ></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>

                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div id="carousel-modal-demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9999999999999">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="7"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="8"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="9"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="10"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="11"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="12"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="13"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-modal-demo" data-slide-to="14"></li>
                        </ol>



                        <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                            <div class="item active"> 
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <main class="item">
                                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>

                            </main>
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div> 
                            <main class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </main>
                            <main class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </main> 
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <p class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </p> 
                            <p class="item"> 
                                <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""/>
                            </p>



                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-modal-demo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-modal-demo" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a> 

                        </div> 
                    </div>  
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should post some code here for us, and maybe some details of the libraries you are using. I had a quick look at your page. For me (in Chrome) the modal works fine, but I see console errors - complaints from bootstrap that jquery ($) is not defined. Check your script loading order. Also repeated errors that "modalImg" is not defined whenever an image is clicked. That should get you started debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ***fotogalerie.html***
.. CALL jquery CDN Before Bootstrap.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Right now you are doing in opposite order. Hence getting the `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` Error

EDIT. Also these CDN should be Called in the body instead of the Head

Comment: I am seeing 2 CDN for bootstrap has been called .3.3.6 & 3.3.7 . One in the Head and One in the Body . We just require 3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js .                                                                                                                                                                        
Could we also remove the above jquery & bootstrap CDN from the Head and place it in  the body

Comment: Ok, uploaded and nothing change again :/

Comment: No  No No... I suggested jquery & boostrap together in the body.. You have left jquery CDN in the head. It should be above boostrap.min.js in the body & get rid of the Async word

Comment: uploaded again .

Comment: does the problem still exists at your end? I am able to slide to the next image  every time on Chrome now.

Comment: When you click on any image it opens the first so it is first image i think.. And I'm seeing it like this https://gyazo.com/58752a72c2e6524eab11696ebe35c9ae

Comment: I am giving it a last try . [Here is what happens when you click on the first image](https://ibb.co/dfnEUQ) . I am using chrome

Comment: Okay. Anyway thanks so much for unblocking it! Really helped :)

Comment: I think i can't with my rep .. sorry :/